# Подскажите, нужно ли писать async для анонимного коллбэка в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Или данный callback по умолчанию является асинхронным?

```
https.createServer(options, async (req, res) => {
    req.on("data", data => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: нет, не нужно..

Comment: Спасибо. Получается все callback-и асинхронны? Это ключевое слово указывается только при создании собственных, именных, асинхронных функций?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, `async` нужно добавлять, только если внутри функции вы используете `await`. Сам по себе callback вряд ли можно называть асинхронным, скорее его можно считать частью одной из асинхронных парадигм, а сам по себе он просто обычная функция. Особенность его природы — служить ответом на завершение асинхронного события.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В большинстве случаях `callback` функции выполняются синхронно, а вызываются асинхронно. Иногда бывает, что функция `callback` вызывается то синхронно, то асинхронно, но такое непредсказуемое поведение является ошибкой проектирования, сложно дебажится и приносит уйму геморроя всем, кто с ней будет работать. Это не значит, что их надо объявлять с ключевым словом `async`, тут речь идет о том, что эта функция выполнится при достижении какого-то результата (получения запроса от API, истечению таймаута, записи в файл и тд).

Сам по себе шаблон обратных вызовов довольно таки стар, и появился задолго до добавления `async` функций.

Но иногда бывает полезно использовать асинхронные функции в `callbacka-x`. Например, если при получении запроса вам надо обратиться к базе данных, то сам запрос к базе данных является асинхронным и в данном случае это уместно.

Comment: Предположим одновременно к серверу подключилось 100 человек. Если коллбэки асинхронно вызываются, но при этом синхронно выполняются, то получается первый коллбэк поставит в очередь все 99 других до тех пор пока не выполнится полностью... Это крайне не желательно... Мне бы хотелось чтобы исполнения кода между всеми запросами выполнялося поочередно и асинхронно... Ну грубо говоря исходя из того времени, которое будет выделено процессором... А так получится 1 запрос может заморозить всех остальных на долгое время, а так хотябы всех обрабатывать будет но по чуть чуть....

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.